# How to save information from barplot() and not displaying the graph

Tags: r, graphics, plot, bar-chart

I have a small question:
let's assume I want to assign the positions of the x ticks of a barplot to a variable for plots later on, however the barplot should not be displayed in the graphical device. How can I assign without plotting?

```
mat = matrix(ncol=5,nrow=3,rnorm(n = 15))
mids = barplot(mat)
```

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Cheers,
tokami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `barplot`, you can provide the `plot = FALSE` parameter:

```
mids = barplot(mat, plot = FALSE)
```